# django.db.utils.DataError: division by zero

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-queryset

I am getting a error in the following line of code:

```
context['stock_margin'] = context['top_stock'].annotate(
                            Avg_purchase = ExpressionWrapper(F('total_puchase') / F('quantity_purchase'), output_field=FloatField()),
                            Avg_sales = ExpressionWrapper(F('total') / F('quantity'), output_field=FloatField()))
```

I am new to django and cant able to figure out why this is happening..

Any idea anyone how to solve this error?

Comment: check the database where any of the columns you have used in the query has `0` value

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I am new to django and cant able to figure out why this is happening..

PostgreSQL raises an error if you divide by zero, since dividing by zero is undefined. Most other databases return `NULL` in that case.

Since [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), we can use [**`NullIf`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/database-functions/#nullif), and thus work with:

```
from django.db.models.functions.comparison import NullIf

context['stock_margin'] = context['top_stock'].annotate(
    Avg_purchase = ExpressionWrapper(
        F('total_puchase') / NullIf(F('quantity_purchase'), 0),
        output_field=FloatField()
    ),
    Avg_sales = ExpressionWrapper(
        F('total') / NullIf(F('quantity'), 0),
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
)
```

Otherwise you can use a [**`Case`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case):

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

context['stock_margin'] = context['top_stock'].annotate(
    Avg_purchase = Case(
        When(quantity_purcase__gt=0, then=F('total_puchase') / F('quantity_purchase')),
        default=None,
        output_field=FloatField()
    ),
    Avg_sales = Case(
        When(quantity__gt=0, then=F('total') / F('quantity')),
        default=None,
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
)
```

In case the `purchase_quantity`/`quantity` is thus greater than zero, we perform the division, otherwise we return `None`. In both cases for records where we divide by zero, we will return `None`.

That being said, it is a bit *odd* that you have objects in your database with `quantity` and `quantity_purchase` being equal to zero. Depending on the use case, you might want to check where you create these objects, and whether you want to avoid that.

Comment: When using NullIf, default value should be 0.0 instead of 0, otherwise the result will be casted into an integer.