# Django order by vote percentage

Tags: python, django

I currently have a post that has upvotes and downvotes.

the model looks something like this

```
class Word(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    upvotes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='threadUpVotes')
    downvotes = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='threaddDownVotes')
```

in my views.py I have so far gotten this far

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

words = Word.objects.filter(name__iexact='test').annotate(
            total_votes=Sum(F('upvotes') + F('downvotes'))).order_by('total_votes')
```

But I'm unsure what to do next to get it to rank by say the one with most upvotes vs downvotes.

Comment: With "*upvotes vs. downvotes*" you mean to subtract these? or determine the percentage of upvotes over the total number of votes?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I wanted ordered by upvotes, I answered the question already, thank you

Comment: what you here do is summing up the primary keys of the users involved. This means that a post with one upvote by user 100 and two dowvnotes with users 5 and 7 will result in a score of ~0.94, whereas a post with one upvote of user 2 and two downvotes by users 6 and 7, will generate a score of ~0.235

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ham many to many field, You should use:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Sum, Count

words = Word.objects.filter(name__iexact='test').annotate(
    total_votes=Count('upvotes') - Count('downvotes')).order_by('-total_votes')
```

or in your answer:

```py
from django.db.models import F, Sum, Count
from django.db.models.functions.comparison import NullIf

words = Word.objects.filter(name__iexact='test').annotate(
    total_votes=Count('upvotes') / NullIf(
        Count('upvotes') + Count('downvotes')
    )).order_by('-total_votes')
```

Comment: Normally you can not use `Sum(Count(...))` since that is a double aggregation. Furthermore here two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s are made, so that means that the two JOINs will "multiply" each other. If there are two upvotes and three downvotes, then the `Count`s will both work over a set of six elements.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks! I change the answer. for distinct you have a good solution but the better is to make "unique to gether" the foreign keys in `threadUpVotes` and `threaddDownVotes`.

Comment: but you can not make it unique together, since the `ManyToManyField`s are implemented in different tables, and even if that is the case, it would not prevent the "multiplication effect" when working with two `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s.

Comment: @mrash how does this work if it's 0 upvotes or downvotes?

Comment: @mrash nvm was a postgres issue when 0, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324020/django-db-utils-dataerror-division-by-zero/56324346#56324346 so `NullIf` adding it to the bottom part solves it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realized after I posted, I sumply had to divided the upvotes by the total number of votes and order in reverse.

```
words = Word.objects.filter(name__iexact='test').annotate(
            total_votes=Sum(F('upvotes'))/Sum(F('upvotes') + F('downvotes'))).order_by('-total_votes')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a [**`Count`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id8) with [**`distinct=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count.distinct), otherwise you will count an upvote as many times there are downvotes and vice versa. We thus can determine the share of upvotes with:

```
from django.db.models import Count

words = Word.objects.filter(
    name__iexact='test'
).annotate(
    total_votes=Count('upvotes', distinct=True) / (Count('upvotes', distinct=True) + Count('downvotes', distinct=True))
).order_by('total_votes')
```